# Download images in async task and show them in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a list of **URLs**, each corresponding to an **image**.

I need to display these images in a `ListView`.

Currently, my approach is pass this `List<String>` containing URLs to a `CustomAdapter (extending BaseAdapater)`.

Each row item in the ListView will be inflated with an `ImageView`.

Then in the `getView()` method, if `currentImageView == null`, then I'll start an `AsyncTask`, which will download the bitmap for that `imageList.get(position)`.

Then in the `postExecute()`, I'll set `currentImageView.setBitmap(downloadedBitmap)`.

In this manner,from inside the adapter, I'll call AsyncTask one-by-one for each image.

If you think, there is something wrong in this approach then please let me know. Also, please suggest the correct approach.

One pitfall with approach I've found in when AsyncTask for a certain list element is in progress & user scrolls down then back up, the same async task will be called again.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

When your views get recycled, the currentImageView will not be null and it will keep displaying the same images. I would suggest using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It takes care of all of that for you, with TONS of extra features like caching and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [library](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

Then in getView method, simply add this code

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image, model.getimageURL(), R.drawable.placeholder);
```

parameter one is your ImageView, second parameter is Image URL, and the last is placeholder image.